# How to Remove a TFS Group

Tags: tfs, permissions, tfs-2015

I'm managing an instance of TFS 2015. I added a special TFS group to a branch to deny access to certain users. I now want to remove this group from the branch, but I don't see how it's possible. I'm currently looking in the **Version Control** tab under the TFS Control Panel for the project, where I added the group to the branch to begin with. Is there a place to specifically remove a TFS group from a branch? Otherwise what is a reasonable work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tfssecurity /g-` to remove a user or a user group from an existing group. More details of [tfssecurity command from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd). A example:

```
tfssecurity /g- groupIdentity memberIdentity [/collection:CollectionURL] [/server:ServerURL]
```

Or, refer to this issue [Cannot remove user/group from area-level, iteration-level, version control, build security setting](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782957/cannot-remove-user-group-from-area-level-iteration-level-version-control-build-security-setting), it seems by design. Please try the method from the comment: *'If your user's permissions are all configured to "not set", then the user will be removed from the dialog the next time you launch it.'*

Comment: Option 2 worked for me, setting all permissions, that I could, to "Not Set".